# How many Twitter and Bootstrap tags do we need?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed yesterday that we had three `twitter*` tags:

- [twitter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) x 8 questions
- [twitter-bootstrap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) x 1 question
- [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) x 1 question

I propose, based on discussion in the answers and comments by @TingL and @blah238, that we tag questions about:

- Twitter (social media) as [twitter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)
- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (HTML, CSS, and JS framework) as [bootstrap-framework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework)
- Non-[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) use of term [bootstrap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) as [bootstrapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) (for which it is now a synonym)

---

Originally, I wrote the following, which can now be disregarded:

> I'm very much in favour of product tags when platforms have thousands
>   of questions, and even version tags for products that have or are
>   expected to have hundreds to thousands of questions in the next year
>   or two.
>
> However, in this case I do not perceive such a trend, so I think we
>   should not break Twitter down any further than the single
>   [twitter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) tag?
>
> The number of questions guideline I use is only a "rule of thumb" so
>   if there should be special consideration for Twitter then I am keen to
>   hear it.
>
> Does anyone think there is a case for more than a single `twitter*`
>   tag?

Comment: It makes sense to drop the specialty twitter tags and keep the single twitter tag.

Comment: They {bootstrap tags} have been removed and will disappear automatically in 24 hours.

Comment: An important point which may have been overlooked is that Twitter is no longer officially associated with the Bootstrap framework; see my updated answer.

Comment: I removed it as bootstrap is not part of twitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter is social-networking web application, and twitter-bootstrap is a popular development framework originated from twitter for creating web application front-ends (including web GIS). In my opinion, these two are quite different. Twitter-bootstrap as a technology is often used in applications that has completely nothing to do with twitter or social networks.As a GIS example, OpenLayer's dev website has an example for ["bootstrapped openlayers"](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/bootstrap.html).

I my opinion, it would be mistaken to use the same `twitter` tag on questions about e.g. the twitter social network data and questions regarding how to use twitter-bootstrap to build a web GIS (the technology).

Also, I wish to add that Bootstrap-3 is not backwards compatible with previous version. There has been a lot of discussion on SO of migration issues from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3. We may or may not be able to cover all bootstrap questions with one `twitter-bootstrap` tag, depending on how much questions are concerned with one version vs the other.

So I think yes, there is a need. I actually was asking (the one question mentioned in the OP) about issues with using bootstrap-3 to create a web GIS. And it would be misleading to tag such as a `twitter` question.

Comment: I am likely to revise my opinion on this because I just looked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=bootstrap+is%3Aquestion and can now see that it is an emerging topic here.  Are you able to estimate how many Bootstrap questions here are 2 vs 3?  Maybe we just need [tag:bootstrap-3] and perhaps [tag:bootstrap-2].  Even if it is owned by Twitter that does not seem to get used as part of its product name - http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @PolyGeo. Honestly, I don't know how many are v2 vs v3. I guess there will be more bootstrap3 as the w3school tutorials for bootstrap is for v3. But the GIS community is primarily using bootstrap2. That's only my guess as I couldn't find many openlayers bootstrap3 examples. I think maybe we can use a single twitter-bootstrap tag, and when (and if) there are many bootstrap questions, bootstrap3 will be already dominant in GIS?

Comment: What's the case for including "twitter" as part of the tag name?  If it is just that Twitter own it, then our norm here is not to include it, but just to use the product name as the tag stem.

Comment: @PolyGeo The concern is that bootstrap is just too much of a common term/method in statistics and probably related fields. It might cause confusion if people come from statistics or data-mining (I am not sure about data-mining).

Comment: That's OK we just need to write a short tag wiki to say explicitly what [tag:bootstrap] means here, and then if any disambiguation is necessary later, then that bridge can be crossed then.  I'm happy to proceed with implementing a [tag:bootstrap] tag now.

Comment: I guess it will be OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how StackOverflow has them:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The full text of the [`bootstrap` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bootstrap/info):

> NOT TO BE CONFUSED WITH Twitter's Bootstrap CSS framework; please see
>   the [twitter-bootstrap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag.
>
> A bootstrap is a series of procedures run when an application starts
>   up or a request over the web is received.
>
> **Resources**
>
> - [Bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping) (Wikipedia)

However, as discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250920/386205), the Bootstrap framework is no longer officially associated with Twitter, so it should not be part of the tag name. They suggest using the tag [bootstrap-framework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework), plus the version-specific tags, instead, which I agree with.

As for the plain [bootstrap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tag, I would prefer it to be made a synonym of the (newly-created) [bootstrapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping), which is the more general term described in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping), which may be applicable to GIS ([particularly in spatial statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29) -- as in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73294/753)).

Comment: Sounds like a good case has been made so I just swapped [tag:bootstrap] and its synonym [tag:twitter-bootstrap] to make the latter the master.  Do you think we need [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3] here?  Or can we assume that for the foreseeable future that the question volume and likely longevity (as in Bootstrap 4 not yet on horizon?) of Bootstrap 3 means no need for a version tag here?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is not that far off: http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2014/10/29/bootstrap-3-3-0-released/

Comment: Let's create a [tag:twitter-bootstrap-4] tag *when* that is released and assume that [tag:twitter-bootstrap] is more or less coextensive with Bootstrap 3 (and a trickle of Bootstrap 2) for now.

Comment: So, actually the [linked discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250920/386205) brings up the point that the Bootstrap framework is no longer officially associated with Twitter, so they suggest using `bootstrap-framework` (plus version tags), which I can get behind. As for the plain `bootstrap` tag, I would prefer it to be made a synonym of `bootstrapping`, which is the more general term described in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping).

Comment: This sounds like the best way to do it, and I plan to set it like that.  However, I may have made too many changes too quickly because the mod tool to do this threw an error.  I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: Should there been another bootstrap tag ? http://esri.github.io/bootstrap-map-js/demo/

Comment: @Mapperz, if there is a question about it `esri-bootstrap-map-js` would be my suggestion, to go along with `esri-leaflet`.

Comment: I think I have the twitter/bootstrap tags sorted for now but let me know if you or @TingL think I missed something important

Comment: any distinctions between Bootstrap-3 and Bootstrap-4 should probably be outside the scope of GIS-SE. That is, if someone is having a problem which depends on the version of Bootstrap, it's almost certainly unrelated to GIS but will be a CSS/HTML/JS issue.